# Setting unit of matrix/ alignment problem

Tags: matrices

How can I get unit of matrix [m] as shown in figure.

[image: required matrix]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:appendrow}
    ScanPos=\left[ \begin{matrix}
        A \\
        B \\
        C\\
    \end{matrix} \right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}   
    -3.3816  & \ -1.6166  & \ 1.75\\ 
    -3.3816  & \ -1.6166 & \  1.5\\ 
    -3.3816 & \ -1.6166  & \  1.25\\
\end{array}\right]{[}m{]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `_{[m]}`?

Comment: What do you mean by "unit of matrix"? Its dimensions, i.e, `$3\times 3$`?

Comment: You need to put the units in `\text{ScanPos[m]}` not in the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost the same solution, slightly improved:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:appendrow}\renewcommand\arraycolsep{0.67em}
  \text{ScanPos}=\begin{bmatrix}
  A \\
  B \\
  C\\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  -3.3816 & -1.6166 & 1.75\\
  -3.3816 & -1.6166 & 1.5\hphantom{0}\\
  -3.3816 & -1.6166 & 1.25\\
  \end{bmatrix}_{[\mathrm m]}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you change `\arraycolsep`?

Comment: @Sigur: To remove the six `\ `  in  the matrix body.

Comment: Ow, I didn't see them. IMHO I wouldn't use them.

Comment: Nor me, but maybe the O.P. has serious reasons for that. Anyway, it's easier to remove  the change in \arraycolsep.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:appendrow}
    \text{ScanPos}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        A B C
    \end{bmatrix}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -3.3816  & \ -1.6166  & \ 1.75\\ 
    -3.3816  & \ -1.6166  & \  1.5\\ 
    -3.3816  & \ -1.6166  & \  1.25\\
    \end{bmatrix}_{[m]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```